# PHP file and array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, file, lines

I am totally lost here, I made a text file with names in it. I would like to assign a array to each name and open it into a php file for displaying on a webpage so I can change things, I just cannot for the life of me figure this out.

```
$lines = file('responders.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES); 
foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) 
{ 
print "<input type='checkbox' name='responders[]' value='" . $line_num . "' >" . $line . " " . $line_num . "<br />\n"; 
}
```

My text file just has names example

```
Jon
Jim
Tim
Tom
Jerry
```

I would like to assign an array somehow to basically say

```
4 Jon
5 Jim
17 Tim
47 Tom
52 Jerry
```

Without having to use a bunch of white space per line. Is it at all possible? Thanks.
In the end I would like to read my mysql database find out whos all listed and put a check mark next to people who is in the mysql field. I used Implode for that if that helps anybody.

Comment: What is the outout you are getting for the, "print "<input type='checkbox' name='responders[]' value='" . $line_num . "' >" . $line . " " . $line_num . "<br />\n";" statement?

Comment: Jack 0 Tom 1
James 2
Mark 3
Jerry 4 Along with check boxes to the left, also pointing out I am changing names just so I dont post somebodys name out there online.

Comment: So, if you are returning the names to each line, what is the problem?

Comment: The problem is, I would like to assign them to there own array number without displaying a bunch of blank spaces

Comment: What is causing the "bunch of blank spaces"  - I don't understand what your problem is, sorry. Would the [`array_combine`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) be of any user for you? It allows you to create an array of key/value pairs without explicit looping. I don't really know where your keys are coming from right now...

Comment: Ill look into the array_combine. As for the blank spaces I am editing my txt file with a bunch of spaces to basically say Jon is at number 4 line Jim as at 5, Tim is at 17 etc if that makes sence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If combine wouldn't work for you you could just explicitly declare the array k/v.

```
$lines = file('responders.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES); 
$nameArray = array();
$i = 0;
foreach ($lines as $line) 
{ 
    echo $i . " > " . $line . "\n"; 
    $nameArray[i] = $line;
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that looks like it will be a lot better. I will give both a try.

Comment: Nice  :)  Let me know if it needs any fixes

Answer (score 0):

There is a more easy way to achieve this:

```
$content = file_get_contents("responders.txt");
if(strlen($content) > 0) {
    $myData= explode(" ", $content);
    if(count($myData) > 0) {
        $c = 1;
        foreach($myData as $value) {
            echo $value . " -> ";
            if($c % 2 == 0) {
                echo "<br />";
            }
            $c++;
        }
    }
}
```